# Write text inside a div from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, button, replace

I have a JavaScript function that uses `document.write()` to write to the page.  My issue is that when I click the button to call the function, `document.write()` replaces what I already had with what I am writing.  Is there a way to write text to a specific div from JavaScript?

**Here is my HTML code:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js">
    </script>
    <script>
        // Calling the Google Maps API
    </script>

    <script>
        <!-- JavaScript to load Google Maps -->
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="content">
        <div id="googleMap"></div>
        <div id="right_pane_results">hi</div>this -->
        <div id="bottom_pane_options">
            <button onclick="todaydate();">Try It</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

**...and my JavaScript code (something I got from the internet just to test):**

```
function todaydate() {
    var today_date = new Date();
    var myyear = today_date.getYear();
    var mymonth = today_date.getMonth() + 1;
    var mytoday = today_date.getDate();

    document.write("<h1>" + myyear + "/" + mymonth + "/"+mytoday + "/h1">);
}
```

I would like the text to be right below the button.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: What specific div do you want to put it in?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should avoid `document.write`. You'd better put your results to another div:

```
 <div id="bottom_pane_options">
     <button onclick="todaydate();">Try It</button>
     <div id="results"></div>   <!-- Added div ! -->
 </div>
```

Then

```
function todaydate() {
    var today_date=new Date();
    var myyear=today_date.getYear();
    var mymonth=today_date.getMonth() + 1;
    var mytoday=today_date.getDate();

    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML ="<h1>" + myyear + "/" + mymonth + "/" + mytoday + "</h1>";
}
```

As you can see, we're writing the results to the `results` div with `.innerHTML`.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: This works, but for best practice you may want to edit/add the semicolons (;) to the end of every JS line in the function. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 2):

To write into a div do the following:

**Step-1:** Give div an `id` or `classname`

```
<div id="txt"></div>
```

**Step-2.** Use `.innerHTML` in the function:

```
document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML="HELLO";
```

Answer (score 2):

HTML Code:

```
<div id="someclass"></div>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("someclass").innerHTML="<h1>some thing you want</h1>";
```

Comment: Maybe change "someClass" to "someID" !! To avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try this...

```
    <!doctype html>
      <html>
       <head>
         <script type="text/javascript" >
                function load() {
                     var div = document.getElementById('data');
                        div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + "Write your New Data" + "<br>";
                      }
         </script>

      <body onload="load()">
         <div id= "data">
             Hello... I am old
         </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

I am calling this on onload() function you can call as per your beed

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell Javascript to perform the action **`onload`**...  Try with this:

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function sayHi(){
    document.getElementById('hi').innerHTML = 'Hi';
  };
</script>
```

then on your HTML:

```
<span id="hi"></span>
```