# how to write in a div in javascrtip?

Tags: javascript, dom

I am a beginner in javascrit. I would like to write in a div according to the name of the form.
When I write in an input it works very well. But when I write in the div it does not work. Can someone show me how to write in the div according to the name of the form? i have this error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined .thank you.

```
             var mycpt =1;

             var coul = (200+(1+0.5)*mycpt*100);
             var div = document.createElement("div");
             div.setAttribute("class","title");
             div.setAttribute("id",`title${mycpt}`);
             div.setAttribute("style","background-color: silver;");
             div.setAttribute("style","position: absolute;");
             div.style.border ="1px solid blue";
             div.style.width="100px";
             div.style.height="200px";
             div.style.top="300px";
             div.style.left=coul+'px';

             var x = document.createElement("FORM");
             x.setAttribute("name","achille");
             x.setAttribute("action", "#");
             x.setAttribute("id", `chatformsss${mycpt}`);
             x.style.position="relative";
             x.style.top="70px";
             var input1 = document.createElement("INPUT");
             input1.setAttribute("type", "text");
             input1.setAttribute("name", `usernamee${mycpt}`);
             input1.setAttribute("id", `usernamee${mycpt}`);
             input1.setAttribute("value","salut");
             input1.style.width="98px";

             var div1 = document.createElement("div");
             div1.setAttribute("id", `messagesdzs${mycpt}`);

              var input2 = document.createElement("INPUT");
              input2.setAttribute("type", "text");
              //input2.setAttribute("size", "11");
              input2.setAttribute("id", `messagee${mycpt}`);
              input2.setAttribute("placeholder", "Message");
              input2.style.width="98px";

             var submit = document.createElement("INPUT");
             submit.setAttribute("type","submit");
             input1.setAttribute("type","text");

             submit.setAttribute("name","submit");
             submit.setAttribute("value","Envoyer");

             document.body.appendChild(div);
             x.appendChild(input1);
             x.appendChild(div1);
             x.appendChild(input2);
             x.appendChild(submit);
             div.appendChild(x);


   document.forms["achille"].elements[`messagesdzs${mycpt}`].innerHTML+="okokokok";
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21078567/write-text-inside-a-div-from-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve it really took me time here is the answer
 document.forms["achille"].querySelector(`div#messagesdzs${mycpt}`).innerHTML+="okokokok";

Answer (score 0):

```
div.setAttribute("id",`title${mycpt}`);
```

your var name is **mycp** without the T in the end

Comment: I corrected the name of the variable thank you. Can you tell me how to write in the div this way?document.forms["achille"].elements[`messagesdzs${mycpt}`].innerHTML="okokok";